# open extend in COBOL not working

Tags: file, io, cobol, logfile

I'm trying to write a subprogram in COBOL to make a logfile called from my main program. I don't want the logfile is cleared every time I call the subprogram so I use 'open extend'. The problem is because of an unknown reason it won't work, the program does nothing. When i change 'open extend' into 'open output' it works but I don't want the file is overwritten every time.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. LOGGER.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
   SELECT LOGFILE ASSIGN TO "LOGFILE.txt"
   ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD LOGFILE.
   copy "FDLOGGER.cpy".
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 LOGFILEBOODSCHAP      PIC X(150) value spaces.

   Procedure division USING LOGFILEBOODSCHAP.
   pgm.
   open EXTEND LOGFILE
   Move Current-time to TIJD
   Move Current-date to DATUM
   Move LOGFILEBOODSCHAP to BOODSCHAP   
   write logrecord
   close LOGFILE
   exit program
   .
```

Comment: Why contantly open and close the file? That is going to be a good deal of overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a guess, as you have not provided much, but if "LOGFILE.txt" does not exist, you will need OPTIONAL on your SELECT.

Suggest you put FILE STATUS checking in your code.

Comment: Also... "COBOL programmers understand why women hate periods."  You REALLY should consider adding periods to the end of your sentences.  A TON of problems can be avoided this way.

Comment: @Buggabill Since COBOL-85 was introduced, sometime in the previous century, only a single sentence (and therefore single period) is required per paragraph/section. I think the recent trend in COBOL programming is to use as few periods as possible - because they can only cause trouble!

Comment: Yes,the fewer full-stops/periods the better. Putting a full-stop in the wrong place can *cause* problems (if "scope-terminators" are not used). Use scope-delimiters. Don't use "NEXT SENTENCE", use CONTINUE instead. Now you have one to end a procedure name, one to end a paragraph/SECTION, one to end a program (if no paragraphs/SECTIONS like the above) and one on the PROCEDURE DIVISION. *IF* amending old programs, take care when inserting full-stops, as if you do it with the "range" of a conditional-statement, you've changed the program logic.

Comment: I get a little antsy when I see no periods.  I have seen some incredibly horrible behavior due to too many/not enough periods. Example of not enough - someone does not terminate an ACCEPT with an END-ACCEPT when it is needed. This seems like a personal preference thing, or are there performance gains to be realized from not using periods?

Comment: Run-time performance, no. Compile-time, I'd guess not much at all if any. Developer-time? Maintainer-time? From pre-Cobol II, the fact that a full-stop/period terminated a condition caused many problems as code was "tossed around" carelessly. It is not the termination of ACCEPT, but the optional condition (ON EXCEPTION/NOT ON EXCEPTION). Yes, if left off for a condition, only a full-stop will save the day. But a full-stop in the wrong place will take the saved day and toss it in the rubbish bin again :-)

Comment: @Buggabill have a look at: [COBOL: The Good, the Bad and the Ugly](http://www3.sympatico.ca/bredam/GoodBadUgly.html)

Comment: @Bill Woodger - Be careful when suggesting to use CONTINUE in place of NEXT SENTENCE. CONTINUE is a no-op while NEXT SENTENCE is a disguised GO TO (end of sentence). Sometimes the difference is very significant in legacy code where scope termination is defined using both COBOL 85 "END-whatever" and periods.

Comment: OK, I should have been explicit. "Use" means coding it yourself. If it is already there, it is different (I'd not touch it without a spec for it, but I would raise an issue if it "looked wrong"). There are still Cobol '74 compilers in action (ICL for instance), so there's no choice there anyway (CONTINUE would get a compile error). Anyone who has deliberately coded "NEXT SENTENCE" with END-IF and a deliberate "target" full-stop later shouldn't be let near a computer. There certainly are these things around, but I hope they were errors rather than deliberate :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is very old here. But I was still having the same problem today and after a few hours I discover that GnuCOBOL 2.0 with OpenCobolIDE 4.7.6 that I am using generates error 35 when trying to use OPEN EXTEND. I solved it in a not very elegant way, but it works perfectly. I am sharing the solution I found.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. CREATFIL.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   REPOSITORY.
       FUNCTION ALL INTRINSIC.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT FD-VIRTUAL ASSIGN TO "CADFILE.TXT"
       ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL
       ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL
       FILE STATUS IS WS-GET-ERROR.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD  FD-VIRTUAL.
   01  FS-BOOK.
       05 NOME PIC X(40).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   77  WS-GET-ERROR      PIC XX.

   LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  TB-VIRTUAL.
       05  TB-BOOK.
           10 LS-NOME    PIC X(40).
   77  LS-ENTER          PIC X.
   77  WS-RESP           PIC A VALUE "Y".

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       OPEN EXTEND FD-VIRTUAL.
       IF WS-GET-ERROR = "35" 
          OPEN OUTPUT FD-VIRTUAL
       END-IF
       IF WS-GET-ERROR = "00"
          PERFORM UNTIL UPPER-CASE(WS-RESP) NOT = "Y"
             DISPLAY X"0D"
             DISPLAY "Name: " WITH NO ADVANCING
             ACCEPT LS-NOME
             WRITE FS-BOOK FROM TB-BOOK
             DISPLAY "More record (Y) for YES " WITH NO ADVANCING
             DISPLAY "- any key for NOT: " 
                WITH NO ADVANCING
             ACCEPT WS-RESP
             IF UPPER-CASE(WS-RESP) NOT = "Y"
                EXIT PERFORM
             END-IF
          END-PERFORM
       END-IF.

       CLOSE FD-VIRTUAL.

       DISPLAY X"0D".
       DISPLAY "Press <ENTER> to finish... " WITH NO ADVANCING.
       ACCEPT LS-ENTER.
       STOP RUN.
   END PROGRAM CREATFIL.
```

Observe the instruction

```
OPEN EXTEND FD-VIRTUAL.
IF WS-GET-ERROR = "35" 
   OPEN OUTPUT FD-VIRTUAL
END-IF
```